# How to create Kibana filter using KQL language

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am exploring Kibana for data exploration, and have created a query using KQL:

```
title:biologist or description:biology
```

I would like to use this same query as a saved filter that I would use in my dashboards.  However, I can not find a way to convert this search to a filter.

I see that filters can be created using "Query DSL" that is a JSON config.  I believe I can find a way to write my KQL search in Query DSL, but it seems there should be a way to convert my KQL search directly to a filter.

Or my understanding of filters vs queries needs some updating.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 2):

Jay, at the moment, Filters in Kibana use the AND syntax, there isn't an option for Or filters. You have a few options to do what you want:
Create a filter with one of the items, e.g. `title:biologist` and a query for the other. You could also edit a filter using DSL. Here's a link to the filters docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/field-filter.html. For DSL, you can have a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html#